# Does "svnlook propget" work?

Tags: svn, pre-commit-hook, svnlook

Okay take a look at the following:

```
1: $ svnlook changed -r2 svn_repos/           
_U  trunk/
2: $ svnlook proplist -r2 -v svn_repos/ trunk 
  foo : bar
3: $ svnlook propget -r2 svn_repos/ foo trunk
4: $ svnlook propget -r2 svn_repos/ fooo trunk
svnlook: Property 'fooo' not found on path 'trunk' in revision 2
5: $
```

I'm using the svnlook command and seem to have a problem. Line #1 shows that there's a property change on `trunk`. Line #2 shows that there's a property called `foo` with a value of `bar`. I did this via ths `svnlook proplist` command. Okay, so far so good.

Line #3 shows the results of a `propget` on property `foo`. It returns nothing. If I mispell the name like I did on line #4, it tells me the property isn't found.

My understanding is that `svnlook propget` is suppose to print the value of the property much like `svn propget` does. In fact:

```
$ svn propget -r2 foo file://$PWD/svn_repos/trunk 
bar
```

Does exactly what I think it should.

Am I missing something. Did I do something wrong. Or is there an issue with the `svnlook` command?

I need this for a Subversion hook, so using `svn` instead of `svnlook` is not a possibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue. It's what my friends in Customer Service call a *Code ID: "Ten-T"*.

```
david@DaveBook:~david
$ svnlook propget -r2 svn_repos/ foo trunk
bardavid@DaveBook:~david
$
```

Look at the third line: There it is: The **`bar`** in front of the **`david`** in my prompt.

I removed the line with the overly complex prompts when I posted it here.

Answer (score 0):

do you need to include the repository path as opposed to just the -r switch?
http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svnlook.c.propget.html

Comment: hmm, apparently according to the syntax of your example 2, it should work... nm.

Comment: thescientist: The repository path is the `svn_repos/`. I'm in my `$HOME` directory and I have my repository in `$HOME/svn_repos`. Giving the full name of the repository path doesn't help. I can't use `svn pget` because I need to be able to use the `-t` parameter and not just the `-r` parameter.